# One search box for multiple search queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a search box that searches for whatever is input (Phone brand, model, operating system and price descending) and have a loop to display each result in a box of its own depending on if the search criteria is met. However, when I add more than one query, one of two of them work and the rest don't. The code is below:

```
mysql_select_db("bg29li", $con);
$phonesearch = $_POST['phonesearch'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `phones` JOIN manufacturer USING (ManufacturerID) JOIN operatingsystem USING (OSID) WHERE Price <='$phonesearch' ORDER BY `Price` DESC";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `phones` JOIN manufacturer USING (ManufacturerID) JOIN operatingsystem USING (OSID) WHERE Model LIKE '%$phonesearch%'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `phones` JOIN manufacturer USING (ManufacturerID) JOIN operatingsystem USING (OSID) WHERE OSName LIKE '%$phonesearch%'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `phones` JOIN manufacturer USING (ManufacturerID) JOIN operatingsystem USING (OSID) WHERE Name LIKE '%$phonesearch%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
```

In this example, only the bottom query seems to work (Fetches the phones with the same brand name than the one that is typed in). I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: That's becouse you're overwriting the $sql variable 3 times

Comment: @user1762928 please do not remove your questions, but just mark the answer as "accepted" - folks having the same problem cannot reuse the solution given here otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the variable `$sql`. Reduce it to one query, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `phones`
JOIN manufacturer USING (ManufacturerID)
JOIN operatingsystem USING (OSID)
WHERE (Price <='$phonesearch')
  OR (Model LIKE '%$phonesearch%')
  OR (OSName LIKE '%$phonesearch%')
  OR (Name LIKE '%$phonesearch%')
ORDER BY `Price` DESC
```

Comment: Additionally, the `mysql_*` functions are in the process of being deprecated, if you are writing new code I'd recommend to use the `mysqli_*` functions or PDO objects with prepared statements.